# Running multithreading in python is suspended

Tags: python, multithreading

I test multithreading in python, but the code is suspended:

```
class MongoInsertThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,  queue, thread_id):
        super(MongoInsertThread, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print(self.thread_id,': ', self.queue.get())

def save_to_mongo_with_thread():
    q = queue.Queue()
    size = int(math.ceil(16 / 3))

    for e in range(size):
        for i in range(e * size, min((e + 1) * size, 16)):
            q.put([i], block=False)
        threads = []
        for i in range(size):
            threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

the result is what I wanted, but the program is not ended, the result is:

```
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
5 :  [5]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [6]
1 :  [7]
2 :  [8]
3 :  [9]
4 :  [10]
5 :  [11]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [12]
1 :  [13]
2 :  [14]
3 :  [15]
```

But it does not print the last `+++++++++++++++++++++++`, How can I deal with it?

Comment: I realize this is an old question but you should consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `q.put()` `16` times - `i in range(e * 5, (e + 1)*5)` for every `e in range(5)` produces

1. `i in range(0, 5)`
2. `i in range(5, 10)`
3. `i in range(10, 15)`
4. `i in range(15, 16)`
5. `i in range(20, 16)`
6. `i in range(25, 16)`

Which will append `16` values to `q`. However you create `25` threads with the associated `25` calls to `q.get()` - but once the first `16` elements have been removed `get()` blocks. If you use `q.get(block=False)` the code will finish successfully but you will get a number of warnings raising `Empty` from `get()`. Changing the loop condition of the loop

```
for i in range(size):
  threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
```

to `range(e * size, min((e + 1) * size, 16))`

Will fix the mismatch. However it is also useful to add a break statement to stop the outermost `for` loop after all `16` elements are added and removed.

### Complete Example

```
class MongoInsertThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,  queue, thread_id):
        super(MongoInsertThread, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print(self.thread_id,': ', self.queue.get(block=False))

def save_to_mongo_with_thread():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    size = int(math.ceil(16 / 3))
    for e in range(5):
        if (e*size > 16): 
            break
        for i in range(e * size, min((e + 1) * size, 16)):
            q.put([i], block=False)
        threads = []
        for i in range(e * size, min((e + 1) * size, 16)):
            threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

Output -

```
0: [0]
1: [1]
2: [2]
3: [3]
4: [4]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
5: [5]
6: [6]
7: [7]
8: [8]
9: [9]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
10: [10]
11: [11]
12: [12]
13: [13]
14: [14]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
15: [15]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Also note that I am using `get(block = False)` to help illuminate future issues, but it is unnecessary for this example.